# Order array list from model function

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, codeigniter, activerecord

I am using the Facebook php sdk in my codeigniter application. The code below checks the **Facebook friends** of the logged in user and matched it against the values on users in the database to check if any of the friends exist as a user of the app.

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

$temp = array();
 foreach ($friends["data"] as $value) {

            $friendid=$this->upload_model->get_user($value["id"]);

              if (($friendid)) {

                $my_friends=$this->upload_model->get_user($value["id"]);
                $temp[]=$my_friends[0];



            }
$data['top_friends'] = $temp;
```

This is done using my model in the controller `$this->upload_model->get_user($val)`.

**The model**:

```
public function get_user($id)
    {
        $this->db->order_by('points', 'desc'); 
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $q=$this->db->get('gamer', 10);
        $data = $q->result_array();
        return $data;
    }
```

The code returns the friends that exist in the database fine, however I would like to order them in descending order of `points` (a column in `gamers`). The model code above should return the top ten friends in terms of points. I want order the gamers by points with the gamer with the most points first.

However, the code doesn't order them, the results are returned and displayed to the view in order of id instead, so in order of how they were entered in the database. How do I order the friends returned so that I can display the top 10 gamers with the highest points in my view. I assumed this would be done in the model query?

**My View**:

```
<?php foreach($top_friends as $friend):?>
<p><?php echo $friend['name']; ?></p>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Would it matter if it is ordered in the model, or in this case, would I have to somehow order it through the `$temp` array seeing as it is passed to this array.

But how would I order this from `$temp`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of sub array sorting.
Try below code:

Add a new function to sort subarray

```
function sort_points($a, $b) {
  return $b["points"] - $b["points"];
}
```

Then call usort function with your array:

```
usort($temp, "sort_points");
```

Comment: Would the function be within the controller function?

Comment: No. If it's controller function, then you should call with `$this`. So   create this function in your helper.

Comment: ok but I don't undertstand what $a and $b are. points is what I want to sort by, I want to sort in desc order, and also I need to limit by 10.

Comment: You are getting only 10 records from db. For $a, $b, check tutorial http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: did check my solution?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46077/discussion-between-tester-and-kumar-v)